# データの列方向への結合

Tags: python, python3, numpy

今まで二つのデータを以下のようなコードで列方向に連結させていました．
それぞれ行*列はdata1は2*32,data2は5*32,data3は8*32の形になっています．
data1とdata2のみのときは以下でできました．(7*32の形になる)

```
import numpy as np
#index削除しているか確認
data1 = np.loadtxt('210122-945and1200-del-stand-t-all.csv', delimiter = ",")
data2 = np.loadtxt('210123-945and1200-del-stand-t-pre.csv', delimiter = ",")
data = np.append(data1,data2,axis=0)
print(data)
```

今回3つ以上のデータを以下のようなコードで連結させるとaxis=0のところでエラーが引っ掛かりました．目指しているのは15*32の形です．

```
import numpy as np
#index削除しているか確認
data1 = np.loadtxt('210122-945and1200-del-stand-t-all.csv', delimiter = ",")
data2 = np.loadtxt('210123-945and1200-del-stand-t-pre.csv', delimiter = ",")
data3 = np.loadtxt('210124-945and1200-del-stand-t-pre.csv', delimiter = ",")
data = np.append(data1,data2,data3,axis=0)
print(data)
```

どうすればスムーズに行けるんでしょうか．そもそもappendを用いるのがだめなんですかね

Comment: 各CSVデータと結合結果のそれぞれの次元数・要素数は何でどうなって欲しいのでしょう？

Comment: 編集させていただきました．プログラミング初心者なのですがこの編集で十分でしょうか

Comment: ちなみに 232,532,832 というのは何かの分野の表記法なのでしょうか？ 何となく感覚的に見当を付けられますが、厳密には何処で区切ってどちらが行か列かが曖昧な表記に思えるのですが。あと 7*32 というのとは統一が取れていませんよね。

Comment: @metropolis さん、概ねそういう形だとは思っていましたが、表記を合わせるなら説明の単語の方は`それぞれ行*列`ではなく`それぞれ列*行`だと思われます。あるいは`行*列`が正しいなら、タイトルや説明1行目の「列方向への結合」「列方向に連結」が間違っていると思われます。いずれにしろ@佐藤 俊介さんの確認待ちでしょうね。

Comment: @kunif 「Markdown を左右に並べる」で確認してもらえば判るかと思いますが、アスタリスク(`*`)が markdown 記法の italic として解釈されているのを修正しただけです。

Comment: @metropolis さん、なるほどそうでしたか。あと更には2つの連結の時に`data = np.append(data1,data2,axis=0)`ということで`axis=0`の指定で出来ていた、こと自体が`列方向に連結`と合っていない気がしますが、それも確認待ちですかね。

Comment: お騒がせしてすいません．列方向て横方向なのですね．おっしゃる通り間違えでした．縦方向への結合でした．こういうのは行方向というのですかね．回答していただいた方法でaxis=0でうまくいきました．ありがとうございました

Answer (score 0):

こちらの記事が参考になるでしょう。
[NumPy配列ndarrayを結合（concatenate, stack, blockなど）](https://note.nkmk.me/python-numpy-concatenate-stack-block/)
[How To Concatenate Arrays in NumPy?](https://cmdlinetips.com/2018/04/how-to-concatenate-arrays-in-numpy/)

[numpy.append(arr, values, axis=None)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) は2つしか配列を指定できないので、

> Parameters
>
> - arr : array_like
>   Values are appended to a copy of this array.
> - values : array_like
>   These values are appended to a copy of arr. It must be of the correct shape (the same shape as arr, excluding axis). If axis is not specified, values can be any shape and will be flattened before use.
> - axis : int, optional
>   The axis along which values are appended. If axis is not given, both arr and values are flattened before use.

それ以上を並列で連結するなら [numpy.concatenate((a1, a2, ...), axis=0, out=None)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) を使えば良いでしょう。(2つの時でも使えます)

> Parameters
>
> - a1, a2, … : sequence of array_like
>   The arrays must have the same shape, except in the dimension corresponding to axis (the first, by default).
> - axis : int, optional
>   The axis along which the arrays will be joined. If axis is None, arrays are flattened before use. Default is 0.
> - out : ndarray, optional
>   If provided, the destination to place the result. The shape must be correct, matching that of what concatenate would have returned if no out argument were specified.

質問のソースで言えば、以下の行を：

```
data = np.append(data1,data2,data3,axis=0)
```

こちらのようにリストやタプルで指定すれば出来るでしょう：

```
data = np.concatenate([data1,data2,data3], axis=1)
```

あるいは：

```
data = np.concatenate((data1,data2,data3), axis=1)
```

---

また [numpy.hstack(tup)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) でも同様に出来て、こちらは`axis=`の指定が不要になります。

> Parameters
>
> - tup : sequence of ndarrays
>   The arrays must have the same shape along all but the second axis, except 1-D arrays which can be any length.

`concatenate`同様、以下になります：

```
data = np.hstack([data1,data2,data3])
```

あるいは：

```
data = np.hstack((data1,data2,data3))
```

---

ちなみに「列方向への結合」というのが誤解で、実は「行方向への結合」であるならば、`concatenate`の`axis=1`パラメータは`axis=0`にするかデフォルトと同じなので不要になり、あるいは`hstack`ではなく [numpy.vstack(tup)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) を使用することになるでしょう。