# Pythonでの文字列配列・数値配列を合わせてcsv出力したい

Tags: python, python3, numpy, csv

Python3でプログラムを書いています。

### 行いたいこと

```
import numpy as np

# vals サイズ[3,5]の数値配列
vals = np.array([
    [  1.0,   2.0,   3.0,   4.0,   5.0],
    [ 10.0,  20.0,  30.0,  40.0,  50.0],
    [100.0, 200.0, 300.0, 400.0, 500.0]
])

# vals サイズ[3]の文字列配列
strs = ['str1','str2','str3',]
```

という配列がある時、以下のようにcsvファイルに書き出したいです。つまり、csvファイル内で3行6列となるように書き出したいです。
**csv出力　理想**

```
str1, 1.0,   2.0,   3.0,   4.0,   5.0
str2, 10.0,  20.0,  30.0,  40.0,  50.0
str3, 100.0, 200.0, 300.0, 400.0, 500.0
```

### 行ってみたこと

数値配列のみの書き出しであれば、
**コード1**

```
import csv
with open('out.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerows(vals)
```

などとして書き出せたのですが、この左側の列に文字列配列を入れ込むことができません。
今試してみた方法は、せめてまず文字列配列の情報を何でも良いから同じcsvに出力することを目指した、コード1のあとに
**コード2**

```
strs2 = [strs] # これがないと1セルに1文字が入ってしまう
with open('out.csv', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerows(strs2)
```

を追加する方法ですが、これだとcsv出力は
**csv出力　現状**

```
1.0,   2.0,   3.0,   4.0,   5.0
10.0,  20.0,  30.0,  40.0,  50.0
100.0, 200.0, 300.0, 400.0, 500.0
str1,  str2,  str3
```

となってしまっています。

`writer.writerows`では行ごとに書かれていくようなので、まずは文字列を縦長に出力することを目指してみたのですが、文字列配列の転置などが上手くいかず(https://jackee777.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/05/03/223646 などのzipを使う方法を試したが、csvの1セルに1文字が出力されてしまった)、手作業でCSV内で列のコピーなどを行っています。

こちら何か良い方法をご存じの方、教えていただけないでしょうか。よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[numpy.column_stack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html#numpy-column-stack) を使って以下の様にも書くことができます。

```py
import csv

with open('out.csv', 'w') as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
  writer.writerows(np.column_stack((strs, vals)))
```

**output.csv**

```
str1,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0
str2,10.0,20.0,30.0,40.0,50.0
str3,100.0,200.0,300.0,400.0,500.0
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！これはとてもシンプルですね！今試してみて、正しく動作することを確認しました。

Comment: 複数の方からご回答頂きましたが、こちらのmetropolis様の案が、最も行数が少なくシンプルで変更量が少なかったため、ベストアンサーとさせて頂きます。勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

数値と文字列が混在するような場合は Pandasが便利です

```py
import pandas as pd
import sys

pd.DataFrame(vals, index=strs)
#          0      1      2      3      4
#str1    1.0    2.0    3.0    4.0    5.0
#str2   10.0   20.0   30.0   40.0   50.0
#str3  100.0  200.0  300.0  400.0  500.0

df = pd.DataFrame(vals, index=strs)

df.to_csv(sys.stdout, header=False)
#str1,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0
#str2,10.0,20.0,30.0,40.0,50.0
#str3,100.0,200.0,300.0,400.0,500.0
```

---

読み込む場合も同じように, Pandasから可能です

```py
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, header=None, index_col=0)
df.values # Numpyデータ
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！！！上手くできました！

Answer (score 1):

`numpy`を使い続ける場合は、こちらの記事 [データの列方向への結合](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/73524/26370) と同様に、文字列も`numpy.array`で2次元に作成して、`hstack()`で結合すれば良いでしょう。

これを：

```
strs = ['str1','str2','str3']
```

このようにして：

```
strs = np.array([['str1'],['str2'],['str3']])
csvdata = np.hstack([strs,vals])
```

結果のcsvdataをcsvファイルに書くのは今までの物が使えるでしょう。

---

あるいはいったん1次元配列を作ってからnumpy.arrayに変換するのなら以下のようにします。

```
strs = ['str1','str2','str3']
strs = np.array(strs).reshape([3,1])
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。変更後のサイズを指定してしまえば良かったのですね。こちらの方法でも上手くできました！